# SQL code it's looks to complicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

Test Table

```
create table Test (
Id integer,  
Store_N  varchar(25),
Department varchar(25)  
);

INSERT INTO Test (Id, Store_N, Department )
Values (25,'1','A'),  (67,'1','A'),  (34,'1','A'), (97,'1','C'),
(21,'1','C'),  (268,'1','B'),  (456,'2','A'), (349,'2','A'),
(935,'2','B'),  (36,'3','B'),  (637,'3','B'), (388,'3','B'),
(891,'3','B'),  (344,'4','A'),  (763,'4','A'), (836,'4','A')


SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( Partition BY Store_N ORDER BY Store_N ) AS AA 
FROM Test;
```

Result is

[image]

I need to exclude all stores which have only one department and have the only DISTINCT department for each store. The result looks like this

[image]

And this is code

```
SELECT DISTINCT TB4.Department, TB4.Store_N
From
(
SELECT TB0.Store_N, TB0.Department FROM Test TB0
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT TB2.Store_N , Count(*) AS AA1
FROM
    (    
     SELECT  DISTINCT TB1.Department , TB1.Store_N 
     FROM  
        ( SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( Partition BY Store_N ORDER BY Store_N )  AA 
         FROM Test ) TB1  
    ) TB2
    group by TB2.Store_N
    HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1 ) TB3 
ON TB0.Store_N = TB3.Store_N
) TB4
```

Now the question how to simplify this code?

Thank you

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, a large dialog was shown to you that strongly suggested you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality differs between them. All you've done by ignoring that suggestion is made sure that it will take longer for you to get an answer, and waste the time of people who answer only to find out it does not apply to your DBMS. Please **don't** ignore dialogs that you see here. They're shown to you for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically do:

```
select store_n, department
from test
group by store_n, department;
```

But, you want to exclude stores that have only one department, so lets do a count:

```
select store_n, department
from (select store_n, department, count(*) over (partition by store_n) as cnt
      from test
      group by store_n, department
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0962b0/3) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon.  It's much simpler.  :-)

Comment: if this is db2 it can be done with an OLAP function.

Answer (score 1):

You are going a long way round to get the functionality of the "GROUP BY" clause

```
SELECT TB2.Store_N , TB2.Department
FROM
    (    
     SELECT  Department , Store_N, count(Id) as c 
     FROM  Test
     GROUP BY Department, Store_N) as TB2
WHERE TB2.c > 1
```

Comment: Thank you, Bijan. It's much simpler. :-)

Comment: Gordon or  Bijan how to add  Id to this result?

Comment: Hi Konstantin, it is very hard to imagine what you are asking to be able to do. That is because by definition of your problem each of our resulting records corresponds to multiple IDs

Comment: After  we select unique combination store and department I need the first Id of this record                                                                                         
 store_n department Id
1            A             25
1            B             268
1            C             97
2            A             456
2            B             935   Unfortunately I don't know how to include image in the comment

Comment: Then simply do an inner join if this results table with the original table and select Id, Department, Store_N

Comment: Join is not working. Could you please look at this two images original table with selected field  https://image.ibb.co/f2SLYG/P1.png t and second image this with result table https://image.ibb.co/dTGQ0w/p2.jpg  Thank you  Bijan for all your help.   Konstantin